# What is gcc -Wstringop-overflow complaining about here?

Tags: c++, gcc-warning

The following code (reduced from a larger, more sensible sample):

```
#include <vector>

void shrink(std::vector<int>& v) {
    while (v.size() > 0) {
        v.resize(v.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

Leads gcc 7.3 to emit this warning ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/qTan4b)):

```
In function 'void shrink(std::vector<int>&)':
cc1plus: warning: 'void* __builtin_memset(void*, int, long unsigned int)':
specified size 18446744073709551612 exceeds maximum object size 9223372036854775807 [-Wstringop-overflow=]
```

I have been staring at this code for close to an hour with a colleague, and it just seems correct to me; what is gcc complaining about?

Comment: The code is clearly correct so it's a bogus warning

Comment: it's somewhat puzzling to me why there are any `memset` calls in the code anyway; is `-O3` still not smart enough to realize the vector is never grown? I would guess the warning pertains to a code path where `v.size() - 1` was considered while the vector was empty

Comment: Seems to be fixed in GCC 8.

Comment: Looks like it was fixed in GCC 8: https://wandbox.org/permlink/qHNcq1h375mdNXNY (GCC 7.3 for comparison: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZIdxVY5FG1eCjxDf)

Answer (score 2):

> it just seems correct to me

The example is correct.

> what is gcc complaining about?

This is a compiler bug. Here is the [bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79095). The bug appears to be fixed in GCC 8.

Comment: Ah nice find! I tried spelunking through the bugzilla, but only found unrelated bugs.